# Posting image using requests on python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to upload an image using requests on python.
This is what I send using browser

```
POST /upload-photo/{res1}/{res2}/{res3}/ HTTP/1.1
Host: tgt.tgdot.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 280487
Authorization: Basic {value}=
Accept: */*
Origin: http://tgt.tgdot.com
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryA8sGeB48ZZCvG127
Referer: http://tgt.tgdot.com/{res1}/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Cookie: fttoken={cookie_value}
```

This is my code

```
with open(os.getcwd()+"/images/thee1.JPG", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    headers = {"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data", "Authorization":"Basic " + authvalue}
    cookie = {cookiename: token.value}
    r = requests.post(url, headers =headers, cookies = cookie, params=encoded_image)
    print r.request.headers
    print r.status_code
    print r.text
```

I keep getting 414 Request-URI Too Large

I'm not sure what's missing here. I would really appreciate help

Comment: How big is the file? And does the API/Server have a max upload size?

Comment: Image used is 544 kb, server max is 10MB

Comment: @heinst: it is not the request *body* that is too large. It is the URI (the URL in this case) that is too large.

Comment: So why are you base64 encoding the image but claiming to upload a multipart/form-data POST body? Your payload doesn't match your content-type header.

Answer (score 6):

You are encoding the whole image into the request parameters, effectively extending the URL by the length of the image.

If you already encoded the image data, use the `data` parameter:

```
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookie, data=encoded_image)
```

Note that `requests` can encode `multipart/form-data` POST bodies directly, there is no need for you to encode it yourself. Use the `files` parameter in that case, passing in a dictionary or sequence of tuples. See the [*POST Multiple Multipart-Encoded Files* section](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files) of the documentation.

The library can also handle a username and password pair to handle the `Authorization` header; simply pass in a `(username, password)` tuple for the `auth` keyword argument.

Encoding an image to Base64 is *not* sufficient however. Your content-type header and your POST payload are not matching. You'd instead post the file with a field name:

```
with open(os.getcwd()+"/images/thee1.JPG", "rb") as image_file:
    files = {'field_name': image_file}
    cookie = {cookiename: token.value}
    r = requests.post(url, cookies = cookie, files=files, auth=(username, password)
```

Comment: Cool, that kind of work on constructing the request but now I'm getting Server Error (500)

Comment: @PyNaobie: and there is nothing I can do to help you with that, not with the amount of context I have here.